# Can't install .exe in wine (RACESTUDIO3)

Tags: software-installation, windows, wine, executable

I am trying to install the Racestudio3 software from AIM https://www.aim-sportline.com/en/sw-fw-download.htm and install it in a Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS throw wine. but I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFRlr.jpg).

Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: It means the program tried to detect your OS and did not find a supported version of Windows, so it shut down. Can you run `winecfg` to see what you wine setting is? It probably reads Windows 7 or Windows XP. Try setting it to a newer Windows version and see if the program detects the new setting?

Comment: @bamm same issue :/